# How to enforce MFA using PowerShell script without being global admin

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

I would like initiate MFA for individual users being having admin roles to AD but am not global admin

i tried using below script but it did not get enabled

set-Msoluser -UserPrincipalName abc@gmail.com -StrongAuthenticationRequirements $mfa

Answer (score 1):

Per documentation, you must be either a global admin or an authentication policy admin:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#authentication-policy-administrator